# Selenium WebDriver Unable to Send Text to InputBox

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

Good afternoon people

How do I use Selenium to enter Login and Password in the Alert Box?

By default when the address is loaded after a few seconds the alert is already displayed:

[image]

Already tried via code:

```
String exePath = "C:\\RegistroES\\Apoio\\IEDriverServer.exe";
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", exePath);
WebDriver driver0 = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver0.manage().window().maximize();
driver0.get("https://detrannet.es.gov.br/controleacesso/login.asp");

driver0.switchTo().activeElement().sendKeys("UsuarioA");
```

But it seems that WebDriver does not see / recognize the alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me this dialog looks like a native/OS-specific 'basic authentication dialog', that pops up if you access some restricted resource with your browser. I'm not 100% sure though - but if it is like I said, then I don't know if you'll be able to use Selenium to automatically enter those credentials, because it's not part of the website your visiting with your WebDriver and because this dialog is not represented by a DOM element in the DOM tree (so not accessible by WebDriver).

Comment: have a look at this video, looks promising: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGAggGbvtw4

Comment: Wow, this video was very instructive, but it did not work in my case, I did a Login step via AutoHotKey anyway, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
driver0.switchTo().alert().sendKeys("UsuarioA")
driver0.switchTo().alert().accept()
```

Comment: Same behavior, it seems that WebDriver can not recognize this Alert as an Atypical Alert

Comment: Maybe you need to wait a bit between them.  Thread.sleep(3000);